# In magento in which file i need to add the code to activate google consumer survery

Tags: magento, survey

I have activated the [google consumer survery](http://google.com/insights/consumersurveys/website_owners)  for my website and also i have got code snippet.In document they have mentioned to input the code just before `</head>` tag.I can't find out this file in magento.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put script in **before  tag** means you can put script in head.phtml

[image]

from `app\design\frontend\YOUR_PACKAGE\YOUR_THEME\template\page\head.phtml`

Comment: Hi i can't find any </head> tag in this file app\design\frontend\default\theme\template\page\html\head.phtml.Exactly where i need to input the code @Keyur Shah

Comment: you can find <head> in your layout file like 1columns.phtml or 2-columns.phtml,it will call head from head.phtml

Comment: so put your script in head.phtml and it will call in head tag

Comment: Yes i have placed my script in head.phtml file but google consumer survey is not working.what will be the reason? @Keyur Shah

Comment: please try to remove all cache

Comment: Even after removed all cache i am not getting the google consumer survey output.I have set First Survey timing also as 1.@Keyur Shah

Comment: have you activate survey? and please cross check with survey document to how to activate

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45781/discussion-between-user2089987-and-keyur-shah)

Comment: have you found solution?

Comment: Currently they have limited google survey only for US,UK and Canada.So we are not able to get any update.@Keyur Shah